# How to use count in ormlite

Tags: android, jquery, database, sqlite, ormlite

```
List<HoraireDb> horaires_reels = null;
try {   
Dao<HoraireDb, Integer> dao = App.getHelper().getHoraireDao();
QueryBuilder<HoraireDb, Integer> builder = dao.queryBuilder();
Where where = builder.where();
where.eq("isprevis", false);
where.and();
where.eq("idactivite", Param.getIdActivite(App.getContext()));
where.and();
where.eq("jour",moment);
where.and();
where.isNotNull("debut");
where.and();
where.isNotNull("fin");
where.and();
where.ne("etat", "D");
where.and();
where.isNull("idabsence");
where.and();
where.lt("fin",moment);

horaires_reels = dao.query(builder.prepare());
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to return an `int` just the number of rows, because returning a list takes too much time. I want to know if there's any way to use `countof()` for in my code?

I found in stackoverflow this answer but didn't work for me :

```
int numRows = dao.queryBuilder().where().eq("name", "Joe Smith").countOf();
```

Comment: Why didn't it work?  What exception or result did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dao = getHelper().getUsuarioDao();
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.setCountOf(true);
queryBuilder.setWhere(queryBuilder.where().eq("name", "Joe Smith" ));
Long usuarios = dao.countOf(queryBuilder.prepare());
Log.d(TAG, "How much name by "Joe Smith" are:" + usuarios);
```

for me this code is ok, I used in a project that is development

I hope that is help.

Comment: The `setCountOf(true)` is done by the `countOf()` method that the user is doing in the post.  This basically doing the same thing as the post.

Comment: when i use : 

`Dao<HoraireDb, Integer> dao = App.getHelper().getHoraireDao();
QueryBuilder<HoraireDb, Integer> builder = dao.queryBuilder();
builder.setCountOf(true);`

they tell me ''The method setCountOf(boolean) is undefined for the type QueryBuilder<EnfantDb,Integer>''
and to fix it i need to add cast to builder

Comment: i slove the problem, the problem was my ormlite-core-4.27.jar i change it to  ormlite-core-4.40.jar and its work, thanks guys for your help